# Using TypeScript and Styled Components `as` prop

Tags: typescript, styled-components, definitelytyped

I have a styled button:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled(Link)`
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px; 
`
```

I can use it as a `Link`:

```
<Button to='/' />
```

But sometimes I would like to use it as an `a`:

```
<Button as='a' href='/' />
```

But in a second case TypeScript is complaining with:

```
Type '{ children: string; as: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ThemedOuterStyledProps<WithOptionalTheme<LinkProps, any>, any>>'.
Property 'to' is missing in type '{ children: string; as: string; href: string; }'.
```

["as" polymorphic prop](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is complaining because your `Link` component that comes from `react-router` requires you to specify a `to` prop. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but `Link` should already render as an `<a />` tag.

If you are willing to render a link to, let's say, an external website, you probably don't want to use a `styled(Link)`, but a `styled.a`.

If you worry about repeating your style for both the `styled(Link)` and `styled.a`, you'd probably want to write a reusable button style using the [css helper function](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) and include it in both of your styled components.

Unfortunately, I believe it is the only option for now, as I have been in a similar case, and tried using `as={Link}` on a `styled.a` and TypeScript complains about unrecognised props. I believe that the implementation of the polymorphic `as` prop on TypeScript is not fully functional so there might be a fix later on.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working due to this `@types/styled-components` issue -> [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30117)

Answer (score 0):

On solution is to add the missing props to the styled element explicitly, like

```
const Button = styled(Link)<{to: any}>`
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px; 
`
```